# In RSpec, what is the difference between stub! and stub?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I've seen it used many times, and never really stopped to question it. Now it's got me wondering if there is a difference between stub and stub!

Is there? Or is it historical? Does stub! mean it stubs it once? and returns back to the normal method call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In both version 2, and v1.3.2, they are simply aliases of each other.  In v1.3.2 `stub` is an alias of `stub!`

https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/v1.3.2/lib/spec/mocks/methods.rb#L12

While in v2.6 of rspec 2, `stub!` is an alias of `stub`

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/methods.rb#L12

However in v1.1.4, `stub` is an alias for `mock`, and `stub!` is a separate method.  From the docs, it would seem that `stub!` in this early version was used to add methods to existing objects, creating a "partial mock".

The explanation:
https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/1.1.4/lib/spec/mocks.rb#L43

The definitions:
https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/1.1.4/lib/spec/mocks/spec_methods.rb#L27
https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/1.1.4/lib/spec/mocks/methods.rb#L12